# Can Vim write incremental lines? i.e. on each line A becomes B, and 1 becomes 2

Tags: macro

I wanted to write this:

```
A = mapping[0]
B = mapping[1]
C = mapping[2]
D = mapping[3]
E = mapping[4]
F = mapping[5]
G = mapping[6]
H = mapping[7]
I = mapping[8]
J = mapping[9]
K = mapping[10]
L = mapping[11]
M = mapping[12]
N = mapping[13]
O = mapping[14]
P = mapping[15]
Q = mapping[16]
R = mapping[17]
S = mapping[18]
T = mapping[19]
U = mapping[20]
V = mapping[21]
W = mapping[22]
X = mapping[23]
Y = mapping[24]
Z = mapping[25]
```

I ended up using LibreCalc, putting the different parts in different cells, adding the letters and numbers, concatenating the results and pasting the lot back into Vim.

I appreciate that what I wanted to write is awful code. I'm studying Python at the moment and have been trying to avoid going to find information myself that I know will be covered later in the course I'm following (http://interactivepython.org/).

The quickest way I knew of to do this in vim was to type something like

```
A = mapping[0] <ESC> hh <CTRL>+<V> BBh y $ o B <ESC> y 1] <CR>
```

I know vim is very powerful (I've been using it for a couple of weeks, am really enjoying it).

Would it have been possible to write what I wanted to with some vim command?

Answer (score 12):

While it can be done with scripting, if you have a very recent version of Vim (e.g. the one in Arch Linux), you can use `g Ctrl-a` to increment a visual block. In your case:

1. Write the original line: `A = mapping[0]` `Esc`
2. Yank line and put 25 copies of it below: `yy25p`
3. Visually select the column containing the `0` char (block selection, using `Ctrl-v`), excluding the `0` from the 1st line (so you end up with a column containing the last 25 zeroes), then increment them with `g Ctrl-a`.
4. Apply the same method for the column containing `A`.

(*Note*: As comments show, one needs to add `alpha` to the `nrformats` options, in order to be able to increment letters, e.g.: `set nrformats+=alpha`.My *vimrc* has: `set nrformats=hex,alpha`, thus disabling octal and binary increment, which I don't use)

Comment: yy isn't working for me. I can see on the cheatsheet I've printed out from www.vimcheatsheet.com that this is a very standard command. vim --version returns this: http://pastebin.com/DcFxZh1S. I'll have to investigate why it's not working for me... (I've tried in visual command and insert modes). Also when I paste, it all appears on the same line. However I've tried out g Ctrl-a and it does exactly what I wanted, thank you :)

Comment: `:verbose map y` should show you what mappings that start with `y` you have, and where they were set. But you have to use `yy` in normal mode.

Comment: That returns: n y<C-G>      *@:call setreg(v:register, <SNR>35_recall())<CR>
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive/plugin/fugitive.vim I'm not using fugitive yet so I'll remove it

Comment: That is OK (no custom `yy`). But make sure you are in normal mode (that's why I put an `Esc` at the end of item 1)

Comment: I appreciated the Esc :). I tried it initially in normal mode. There must be something wrong with my vim installation. I think Rod Howard was having the [same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561706/vim-yank-does-not-seem-to-work), I'll re-install as he suggests. System clipboard integration hasn't been working anyway and I need +python3 so it was on my todo. `g Ctrl-a` was what I needed, thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome and good luck with fixing it :)

Comment: Fixed :D https://asciinema.org/a/2zqavz00sbzvumxwg742h3ozi

Comment: What version of `vim` will increment `A` to `B` with the `Ctrl-a` action? Mine definitely does not, and I'm on `7.4 1-1202`.

Comment: @CoryKlein Try typing `:set nrformats+=alpha`. It will add the value `alpha` to the option `'nrformats'` and should allow `Ctrl-a` to "increment" alphabetical characters. If you like this behavior, you could add it to your vimrc. Otherwise, you could add it to the option with the operator `+=` and remove it afterwards with the operator `-=` (`:set nrformats-=alpha`).

Answer (score 6):

I prefer the visual increment solution that @VanLaser used (See `:h v_CTRL-A`). However I will show this can be done via macro as well.

Start with:

```
A = mapping[0]
```

Record the following keypresses into a macro of your choice (e.g `q`):

```
yyp:set nrformats+=alpha<cr><c-a>:set nrformats-=alpha<c-a>
```

This will duplicate the line and then increment the first character (e.g. `A`) and then increment the number portion. Run this macro 24 times and you are done, e.g. `24@q`.

- `qq` - start recording into register `q`
- `yyp` - duplicate the line
- `:set nrformats+=alpha<cr>` - `'nrformats` does not have `alpha` by default
- `<c-a>` - With `alpha` we can now increment letters
- `:set nrformats-=alpha<cr>` - remove `alpha` from `'nrformats'`
- `<c-a>` - increment the next number
- `q` - stop recording
- `24@q` - replay macro in register `q` 24 times

For more help see:

```
:h q
:h @
:h yy
:h p
:h 'nrformats'
:h :set
:h CTRL-A
:h v_CTRL-A
```

Comment: Nice one :) 25?

Comment: @VanLaser: 1 (starting line) + 1 (recording the macro) + 24 = 26.

Answer (score 4):

Fine answers already provided, I wouldn't have thought to go about it as nicely. I would have typed out all the letters on a single line and then introduced text and line break with an expression substitution (using line number for incremental number), something like

```
iABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ<Esc>:s/./\=submatch(0)." = mapping[".line('.')."]\n"/g
```

Comment: very cool ! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Almost always when doing something like this, I choose to use `:substitute` over macros. Especially the capability to evaluate expression in replacement when starting with `\=` makes it often possible (see `:h sub-replace-special`).

Once you have empty lines in place (`25i<Enter><Esc>`), you can use command

```
:1,26s/^/\=nr2char(line('.')+64) . ' = mapping[' . (line('.')-1) . ']'
```

the necessary sequences are generated using current line (`'.'` argument) number returned by function `line()`, and using nr2char() to convert decimal numbers to ASCII equivalents (65 = A). Necessary strings are concatenated using `.`

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to use the operating system...

```
:r ! perl -E 'for(A..Z){say "$_ = mapping[", ord($_)-64 ,"]"}'
```

Comment: Perl isn't in the operating system.